# end anchor in regex with grep not working

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am attempting to list files that *don't* end in `gz`

I have a minimal working example:

```
ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | grep -v gz$
```

should show empty, but the file still shows, with or without quotes.

I have also tried

```
ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | grep -vP gz$
```

but this fails as well.

```
ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | grep -vE 'gz$'
```

also fails.

I have read [Correct regex not working in grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499897/correct-regex-not-working-in-grep) and [Anchors not working with grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196611/anchors-not-working-with-grep) but I don't see anything there that would solve this problem.

Comment: Is your question about this specific `grep` example or about listing the files, because `!(*.gz)` would expand to the list of non-hidden filenames that don't end in `.gz` in `bash` if you enable the `extglob` shell option.

Comment: @Kusalananda this question is about grep

Comment: And what's the output of `ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`?

Comment: Also what's the output of `type ll`? `ll` is not a standard command, but is often found as an alias for `ls -l` with possibly other options

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the file still shows, and `type ll` shows `ll is aliased to `ls -alF'`

Comment: The question is what else it shows. For instance, with `-F`, if the `gz` file had execute permissions, you'd get a `*` appended. And `sed -n l` would show `...gz*$` (`$` to show the end of line)

Comment: @thanasisp I only list the file as a test, `ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | grep -v 'gz$'` still shows the file

Comment: @thanasisp, I already requested a `set -n l` output which is more portable and more usable than `cat -A` for that purpose.

Comment: You may also want to check what `ls` is aliased to (`type ls`). If it was aliased to `ls --color=always`, you'd likely get colour-reset escape sequences after the file name.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the coloring is messing up the `grep` command.

`ls --color=never -l chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | grep -v gz$` works.  If you write this down, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Those escape sequences would have shown in the output of `ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`. Did you try that?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, `ll chrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`

gives
`-rw-r--r-- 1 con domain users 5018 Sep 18  2020 \033[0m\033[01;\
31mchrX_PAR1.phased.vcf.gz\033[0m$`

Comment: @con Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question. This way it would be easier to show commands and the corresponding output as code blocks, and all relevant information would be in one place, not scattered in question and comments.